# Change `UIView` Width as per `UILabel` Text in `UITableViewCell`

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

In my `UITableViewCell` there's `UIView` with Width Constraint and inside it there's Image and `UILabel`.

Answer (score 1):

Add your view inside `UIStackView` and inside that view add your label and imageView and set proper constraint to label and imageView. and remove all code for calculation of size.

Comment: L --> Left R --> Right T --> Top B --> BottomUITableViewCell --> StackView with L, T, R, B Constraint,                                   StackView --> UiVIew with L, T, R, B Constraint,                                                 UiView --> ImageView with L, T, H, W                                                                  
                 UILabel with L,T, R, H                                                                          
                 UILabel with L, T, R, B but nothing happen cell display as full width, pls see my updated question.

Comment: UIView width are messed up or not set properly . i cant see your problem in screenshot. can you elaborate ? is this screenshot captured with my answer ?

Comment: can i need to give constraint to StackView as well as it's subview like UIView, UILabel, imageView? now UIView has no width constraint

Comment: you need to give constraint to stackview - (L, T , T , B to cell) and not the view  and then UIImageView - L, T , H, W , Label1 -( L to imageview), T, T,( B to label 2) , Label2 - L,T, T,(B to view)

Comment: yes you need to give bottom constraint to view to second label or third label.

Comment: yes i already give both below 2 label bottom constraint to uiview which is inside stackview

Comment: sorry, 2nd label bottom is third label, now i change it's bottom to uiview, but now it will display full comment like i uploaded in screenshot.

Comment: yes , you need to connect top to bottom constraint of subview with  UIView. because cell calculate height with top and bottom constraint.

Comment: don't know what i am missing, but still view is display in full width.

Comment: i created new demo, and it's looks like in my question screenshot.

Comment: you have not assign constraints as i suggested which shown in screenshot.

Comment: now i set constraint as you suggested and now my cell looks like in screen that i upload but it will not compressing width in small comments. pls look at my demo project constraint or suggest me to do compression as per small comments.

Comment: pankilpatel9999@gmail.com

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147162/discussion-between-kkrocks-and-pankil).

Answer (score 0):

Use `UIStackView`. You don't have to think about anything.

[image]

[image]

Comment: can i need to give constraint to StackView as well as it's subview like UIView, UILabel, imageView?

Comment: u need to give constraint for stackview as well as its subviews. but second one depends on your needs

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `arrAlreadyChangeCellFrames`. A cell that was set once for one object can be reset for a different object so it has to be resized.

Tableviews and Collectionview work by reusing the cells. So that even if you scroll very fast there will only be a handful of cells in memory. Because of this there is a very important rule to always follow in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`: **every *if* must have an *else***.  Because the cell can be reused anything that you set in one case must be unset in the other case.

Also, for most layouts you should not need to set the width of label when the text changes.  Just set the width to the maximum size that it is allowed to be and the text will fill up as much as it can.