# Label size is not changing

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uilabel

I am trying to make a Chat app. I have a `tableView` and prototype cell in which I have `UILabel`. But I am stuck with label size(HxW). Please take a look in the image below:

[image]

The first label is taking extra width and height is less. I want that label should take width according to its content but till the button.

These are the contraints:

[image]

For the height I am using:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
    return  UITableViewAutomaticDimension

}
```

Comment: Set the trailing constraint of label less than or equal to a constant value

Comment: Set your label lines to 0 and see if it works. Also do not set the height.

Comment: Have you tried increasing the content hugging priority in the vertical and horizontal directions?

Comment: You just need to give you StackView Trailing constraint constant to >= and it will automatically compressed as per text. I am facing same Problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44649772/change-uiview-width-as-per-uilabel-text-in-uitableviewcell

Comment: By giving trailing >= not occupying the space after text,as you can see in first image 'Great' label has much width and less height.